# Компиляция файлов C и С++ вместе

Tags: c++, c, функции

Есть два файла: A.c и B.cpp. Я хочу использовать в файле А некоторые функции из файла В, вопрос, возможно ли это, и как это можно реализовать. К примеру, в Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае вам следует объявить в соответствующем заголовочном файле  те функции из файла  `B.cpp` , которые вы хотите использовать в файле `A.c` , как имеющие соглашения о связях языка C.

Например,

```
extern "C"
{
   void func1();
   //...
}
```

Иначе редактор связей их может не увидеть.

Comment: или в одну строку `extern "C" void func1()`

Answer (score -1):

Выносите в `B.hpp` прототипы функций из `B.cpp`, в `A.cpp`  - `#include "B.hpp"`. А вообще это в любой книге написано. Вас заминусуют.

Comment: В A синтаксис языка С, может вы имели ввиду A.c? 
Нужно чтобы А скомпилировалось интепритатором С, а В интерпритатором С++, при этом чтобы вызов функций был доступен в А из В.